# How to clone the inner html of a list in query and wrap it

Tags: jquery, html, clone, css-transitions

This is what my CMS will generate

```
<ul>
    <li>something 1<span>subline</span></li>
    <li>something 2<span>subline</span></li>
    <li>something 3<span>subline</span></li>
</ul>
```

This is what I desire to have later, I want to clone the contents of every `<li>` and then put wrap it inside a `<span>` and put in on the front of it.

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="slidein">something 1<span>subline</span></span>something <span>subline</span></li>
    <li><span class="slidein">something 2<span>subline</span></span>something <span>subline</span></li>
    <li><span class="slidein">something 3<span>subline</span></span>something <span>subline</span></li>
</ul>
```

My problem ist that I know little about jQuery, I know functions like `html(), appendTo(), clone()`, ... but my attempts putting them all together to make this work failed.

One of my problem is I don't know how to deal with `self` in one attempt I had self just did not work. do I need to use a `each()` function? I am sure the will be many ways to do this but whats the most easy to understand code?

I intend to use the cloned span, you guessed it, to slide it in on hover with another color style. I think I have to clone this and CSS only won't work if I want to move the exact same content before it right?

solved:

```
(function($) {
    $('ul > li').each(function(){
        var html = $(this).html();
        $(this).html('<span class="slideIn">' + html + '</span>' + html);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: and he alter edited it after i told him my solution btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('ul li').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).html();
        $(this).html('<span class="slidein">' + text + '</span>')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [.wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) function ;)

```
$("ul > li").wrapInner("<span class='slidein' />")
```

Comment: This is better than my answer. so deleting it.

Comment: @karthikr actually it is not because you both not read carefully, I needed to clone the content, then wrap only the cloned part not just everything and your answer actually helped me with that. I used html() insead of text() and modified the function further look my answer.

Comment: @Wayne, Please don't answer your question inside your question.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell why not? I can't answer it down here without any rep. it told me. So this is the only way of doing it.